# Getting comment count per post not working

Tags: functions, count, comments

I have this function:

```
<?php $popular = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=5'); ?>
    <?php while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post(); ?> 
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Where I added `$popular->wp_comment_count`, but it did not work at all. How do I do this? I want to let see the comment count per post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $popular = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=5'); ?>
<?php while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> has <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>.</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number).

Answer (score 6):

There is no `wp_comment_count` in a `WP_Query` object, either in the "top" level as in your code-- `$popular->wp_comment_count`-- or in the individual post objects which is what you actually want to be checking.

There is a `comment_count` in the post objects though, and that is what you want-- `$post->comment_count`.

Your code should look like this (cleaned up and formatted into something readable):

```
while ($popular->have_posts()) : 
  $popular->the_post(); ?> 
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </li><?php 
  echo $post->comment_count; // here is your count
endwhile;
```

Notice that you are checking `$post` for the comment count. `$post` is a global set for each item in the Loop by `$popular->the_post()`. If you are trying to display the count, as opposed to do some other operations based on the comment count, you should probably use `comments_number` as in the answer by @NathanPowell

Answer (score 0):

Use my way

```
<?php
$commentscount = get_comments_number();
if($commentscount == 1): $commenttext = 'comment'; endif;
if($commentscount > 1 || $commentscount == 0): $commenttext = 'comments'; endif;
echo $commentscount.' '.$commenttext;
?>
```

its working in all version.

Comment: Can you add context on why this is the "correct" way to grab the comment count?

The [get_comments_number](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number/) function returns the same count as `$post->comment_count;` just does the query for you.